# How can I pass a string from textInput to a function (like nls) in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I want to write a shiny app which should calculate the parameters of a nonlinear fit-function. To calculate a nls one needs start values for the used parameters. So ideally the user should be able to write a formula in one textInput and to set the start values for the used parameters in an extra textInput, like  `a*x^2`  and `a=1`.

Now I am having a hard time to pass the entry of the second textInput to the  `start` argument of `nls()`.

`start=input$set_start` does not work, it says "invalid first argument" I tried to get rid of the quotations via `noquote()` and `as.name()` and tried to get the value with `get()` but there it says "object 'a=1' not found" has anybody a solution for this task?

The example below is not working in this setup, but if you set the start value directly and type in `a=1` instead of `start=input$set_start` it works

```
   library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
         textInput("set_start","set startparameters",value = "a=1"),
         verbatimTextOutput("nls_summary")
      )
   )


server <- function(input, output) {
   
df<-data.frame(y=c(1,3,8,17,26),x=c(1,2,3,4,5))
output$nls_summary<-renderPrint({
              nls(formula="y~a*x^2",
                  data=df,
                  start=input$set_start)
})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only direct solution to your problem I could find is to use the dreaded `eval(parse(text="xyzzy"))`, which initially seemed a bit of an overkill.

Moreover, to build the `list` properly it is better eval parse the entire expression, as in `start = list(a=1)`.

```
    st <- paste0("list(",input$set_start, ")")
    nls(formula="y~a*x^2",
       data=df,
       start=eval(parse(text=st)) )
```

The simpler alternative would be to input a value rather than an expression and use it directly -:)

Comment: Thank you! :)that works perfectly. 
My intend was to keep the app more flexible, so that the user can insert any number of parameters, as long as he sets a start value. 
The alternative would be a flexible uiOutput, that would generate a textInput for each used parameter to set the start values. 
But I think this solution is more straightforward ;)